# Check if a file is plain text in C

Tags: c, linux, file, types

Is there any way to check in Linux C if a file is a text file, e.g. UTF or ASCII? In bash, we have the program `file`. Is there any equivalent in C?

This is my function to validate a text file in C. I use `popen`, but it does not work fine. Sometimes I have an error in `pclose`. What would I need to edit in the code?

```
int check_file(char *path)
{
 FILE *file_type;
 char command[] = "/usr/bin/file";
 char command_to_execute[512];
 char check[512];
 int correct = 0;
 sprintf(command_to_execute,"%s %s",command,path);
 file_type = popen(command_to_execute,"r");
 if(file_type == NULL)
 {
   return correct;
 }
 fgets(check,512,file_type);
 char *pointer;
 pointer = strstr(check,"ASCII"); 
 if(pointer != NULL)
    correct = 1;
 pointer = strstr(check,"UTF");
 if(pointer != NULL)    
    correct = 1;          
 pclose(file_type);
 return correct;
}
```

Comment: There's the `libmagic` library that is used to implement `file`.

Comment: Read the file and see if it contains text or not.

Comment: system("file "+nameOfUfile);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file` is a program (not a bash function); you could read the file and check for non-ascii characters. If you find any output `false` and stop processing, if you reach the end of the file output `true`.

Comment: Correct, but for plain ASCII files only. Even then: "ASCII" (or "ascci" as the OP names it) is a slippery concept. Is Backspace allowed? Is Form Feed allowed? Is CTR+Z a valid end-of-file (even when followed by binary garbage) or does it lead to "not-plain text"? UTF8/UTF16 has similar problems: you may be able to prove it only contains valid UTF8/UTF16 sequences, but that in itself says nothing. (Although the inverse -- an *invalid* sequence -- proves it's not a text file.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libicu](http://site.icu-project.org/) to test if a string matches a certain encoding. [Iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)
is another alternative